# Crystal to SSRS conversion

Tags: reporting-services

```
DateValue(ToNumber(Mid({Command.Next_coupon_underlying_test}, 1, 4)),
    ToNumber(Mid({Command.Next_coupon_underlying_test}, 6, 2)),
    ToNumber(Mid({Command.Next_coupon_underlying_test}, 9, 2)))
```

I need to have SSRS Expression

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read this article regarding what is expected when asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have no supplied any sample data/values I can only assume that you have a date column that contains a date as a string in the format `"2022-11-30"` and that you want to convert this into a real date.

If this is true then you can do one of two things.

```
=CDate(Fields!myFieldName.Value)
```

Or if you really want to replicate the functionality of your existing expression then something like this...

```
=DATESERIAL(
    MID(Fields!myFieldName.Value,1,4),
    MID(Fields!myFieldName.Value,6,2),
    MID(Fields!myFieldName.Value,9,2)
    )
```

If this is not helpful, please **edit** your question and provide more information.